# Excel Match with multiple criterion not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

long-time since I've used these forums, I've got a mock up of a spreadsheet in the image below. I need to use match to check for two features. The third column is just an ID so that if the output worked I could check to see it is right.

The actual date is a name and then a number, manually entered. When I use match with two criteria it returns #N/A. I have even gone through each line with a AND() function to check that there is a true value, which does return True when it ought to. I need the position of the data, not the data itself as it is used in various INDIRECTs later.

Below is formula that I use. I can get induvial criterion to work, but when there are multiple it doesn't work.

```
=MATCH(TRUE,(B11:B16=H10)*(C11:C16=H11),0)
```

[image]

I have read the other questions on the forum regarding the topic but none of them are the same or I can use anything from them. Any more info needed let me know, and whether you can provide a pointer or a solution that would be great. I am using ctrl+shft+enter to save the formula as well.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you could try: `=LOOKUP(2,1/((B11:B16=H10)*(C11:C16=H11)),D11:D16)`

Comment: @JvdV Although this does work, it returns the value not the location in the data,  have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: *"used in various `INDIRECT()` later"*. To be honest, that sounds like you are manufacturing a volatile roundabout route to an answer you may well be able to achieve in a different, better, way. What is it you are *actually* trying to achieve here.

Comment: @JvdV I have a number of staff, of which are assigned a "rank" I then pull these data over to another sheet, along with data assigned to them, so I used INDIRECT() to pull the data through. The major issue, and why I have been using MATCH() is because I only want some of the staff pulled over, when their rank is between certain levels .i.e. not all the bottom rank or the highest. This is more of a hobby spreadsheet than an official document used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression `(B11:B16=H10)*(C11:C16=H11)` return number not bool. Try:

```
=MATCH(1,(B11:B16=H10)*(C11:C16=H11),0)
```

or

```
=MATCH(TRUE,((B11:B16=H10)*(C11:C16=H11))>0,0)
```

Comment: Do you enter formula as array formula using ```ctrl + shift + enter```?

Comment: I have removed my previous comments, I have reread your answer and realsed the difference, equals vs less than etc and on watching the formula evaluation understand why this works. I have accepted your answer. Thanks for the help